# Spark: Slow implementation of reduceByKey()

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, mapreduce, rdd

We're implementing a task where we are supposed to analyze a dataset.

For some background, the dataset is a large lits of reviews on the following format:

```
"review_id", "user_id", "business_id", "review_text", "review_date"
```

, and this is our current spark conig

```py
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(APP_NAME).setMaster("local")
conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "16g")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "16g")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Our task is to find the polarity *(positivity/negetivity)* of each review using **Spark RDDs**. This part is done by using `.map()` to create tuples on the format

```
(business_id, review_text)
```

, followed by a `.map()` that tranformes each tuple into

```
(business_id, polarity_score)
```

When this is applied to the whole dataset (RDD), we can take out a sample and see the structure of the data at this point. For our dataset, this is around 870 000 rows.

```py
[
   ('TvVX8dHRKOwYCCAZaqysXw', 3), 
   ('wIGw7QrBwYdYeCfdn1qTLA', -2),
   ... 400 more
]
```

For testing, we're running small parts of the dataset *(0.0005)* with the following code. This gives us a subset of about 400 reviews.

```
subset_of_reviews_decoded = reviews_decoded.sample(False, 0.0005, None)
```

If we proceed with the logic explained above we run the following code, and print 10 of them to see if it's working as intended.

```py
# Format = (business_id, value_of_words)
  to_values = filtered_reviews.mapValues(lambda words: convert_to_values(words))
  print(to_values.take(10))
```

```
[
   ('TvVX8dHRKOwYCCAZaqysXw', 3), 
   ('-Kotg2VsVsU5CSjVx3tmmg', 7), 
   ('tSrkbnxjwNTVqQ0l5BaDNw', 21), 
   ... 7 more
]
```

We get to this step with only a couple of seconds of runtime, so we are happy with this. The next step is then to `.reduceByKey()`, since we want to combine the values for all equal keys. All our research shows that this is the correct way to do it, and the [documentation for pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.reduceByKey) lists this exact problem as an example.

So with this in mind we wrote the following code:

```py
# Format = ( unique_business_id, sum_value_of_words)
  reduced = to_values.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
  print(reduced.take(10))
```

This is where the problem of arrises. The code does the right thing, but the runtime is enormous. As one can see below each executor task takes approximately **750ms**, and there is a total of 33 tasks. This is not that bad, but this is when running on a subset of size **0.0005**

```
20/03/29 21:17:54 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 21.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 24) in 749 ms on localhost (executor driver) (22/33)
```

If we increase the subset to **0.0010** (double) == **750ms**

```
20/03/29 21:21:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 6.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9) in 767 ms on localhost (executor driver) (7/33)
```

If we increase the subset to **0.0020** (double) == **1100ms**

```
20/03/29 21:22:27 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 5) in 1196 ms on localhost (executor driver) (3/33)
```

If we increase the subset to **0.0100** (quintuple)  == **3400ms**

```
20/03/29 21:24:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 5) in 3386 ms on localhost (executor driver) (3/33)
```

We finally reached 1% of the dataset, and then each step takes **3400ms**. We think that our dataset of 870 000 rows is rather small compared to real big data, and we cant see how our simple `reduceByKey()` method with an `add` accumulator can use *(3,4sec * 33steps)* 112 seconds when running on 1% of this small dataset.

Are we doing something terribly wrong with applying `reduceByKey()` here?

*PS: Using Dataframes is specifically not allowed*

Comment: I do not see number of executors and cores configured in your application. If that is the case I believe it is running with default values for them which I think it is 2. Also if keys are very different than each other the HashPartitioner(default) might partition them in too many small partitions and spark spending more time scheduling and arranging tasks for small partitions.

Comment: @Amit You are correct that I have not configured executors and cores. For cores, I know that it's only running on one thread, which is the default. I thought about upping the numbers, but thought that the error must stem from an underlying issue. I just ran the calculation on 10% of the dataset, and it took 16min. Upping it might reduce this by 25 or 50%, but I still believe it's unreasonably slow and giving it more resources seems like a bandaid.

I have not heard about bumping the number of executors and will look into this, thanks.

Comment: For your 10% dataset how many partitions you have. Increasing number of executors is not bandaid in all scenarios but it will increase parallelism as well.

Comment: Not sure how partitions I have, but after working some more and testing I think it's actually the `convert_to_values()` method that is slow. I originally thought that this method was fast enough since I could get to the `print(to_values.take(10))` line very fast. After commenting out and testing, I no longer think this is the case.

I think the fault lies in my understanding of the spark runtime. What runs when, and what's taking the time. The `convert` function (pure python) has been the bottleneck the entire time, but its slowness only appears when `reducebykey` runs.

Comment: I think I was tricked by the speed of `print(to_values.take(10))`, thinking that the whole `RDD` was processed by this point, but I now think only a part of the `RDD` is processed.

Comment: That's not `reduceByKey`. That's `groupByKey` [hidden behind `reduceByKey`](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/04_rdd_actions_and_transformations_by_example.md#be-smart-about-groupbykey)